Pacifica certainly won’t start
I have a 2006 Chrysler Pacifica touring. I put a new battery in it about five months ago. I let it sit for about three days and went to start it again. I had no power jumped it and it did start went and drove around lights worked everything worked in the car and then I parked when I went to start again, right after I parked it had no power would this be a battery or an alternator problem?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

More than likely this is a battery problem. The only real way to tell for sure is to put a charger on the battery and slowly let it charge. If it doesn't get back up to full charge after a long charging period (several hours at lower amperage) then there is probably an issue with it. You can check the voltage before trying to charge it with a multimeter, and then again after charging to see the difference. The voltage when fully charged should be somewhere around 13.1-13.5vdc. When the engine is running, the voltage should be around 13.5-14.1vdc. (NOTE: These voltages are in general ... your vehicle may be a little different to the +/-.) Since the battery is only 5 months old, you should still have a warranty on it and should be able to get it exchanged for new if it doesn't recharge.
A different problem which it sounds like you have is there may be a power drain somewhere in your vehicle. Is it possible you may have left a light on or something? That would be an obvious thing, but maybe you didn't notice.
As far as the alternator is concerned, considering it ran just fine, I'd suggest this is not an issue. The alternator isn't actually designed to fully recharge a dead battery. What it's designed to do is top off the battery after starting, then provide the power needed to keep things going.
